# Change Laravel Migration Status

Tags: php, laravel, database-migration

I have mistakenly deleted the records of migration table in Laravel 5.5.
Now when i run `php artisan migrate:status` it shows the status of every migration as 'Not run'. How do the change the status of migration to 'Y'. I don't want run migrations that already ran before or run `migrate:refresh` or `migrate:rollback`.
Using backup of the database, i have also imported the records of migration table but still the status does not changes.

Answer (score 0):

Migrations table has 3 columns: `id`, `migration` and `batch`. In my migrations table `batch` is always 1. Column `migration` contains the file names of the migration classes, so for example, file `2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php` will be `2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table` in the `migration` column.
So from this information you can generate your own sql query to populate the migrations table.
I suggest starting by cd into your migrations folder

`cd project_name/database/migrations`

and then running

`ls > ./migrations.sql`

From there you can edit the migrations.sql file and make it into an INSERT  INTO statement. I haven't tested this so I can't claim this will work.